# How to exclude MySQL query from my loop (limit unnecessary queries)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm asking MySQL for data, but it slows down the whole script. Yet I have no idea how to get this out of a loop. I tried converting it to PHP array but honestly after day of tries I failed.

```
<?php

$id = '1';

include_once 'include_once/connect.php';

for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {
for ($y = 1; $y <= 5; $y++) {

    $xy = $x."x".$y;

    $pullMapInfo = "SELECT value FROM mapinfo WHERE id='".$id."' AND xy='".$xy."'";
    $pullMapInfo2 = mysql_query($pullMapInfo) or die('error here');

    if ($pullMapInfo3 = mysql_fetch_array($pullMapInfo2)) {
        #some code
    } else {
        #some code
    }
}
}

?>
```

How to get MySQL query `$pullMapInfo2` out of loop to shorten loading it by asking once?

If you want to fire script on your localhost you can c&p whole thing :-)

Comment: `(ix, xy) IN ((1, '2x3'), (3, '4x5'), ...)`

Comment: First, mysql_* functions have been deprecated and will be removed from PHP. Second, don't use `die()` for error handling, use throw new `Exception("Meaningfull error message here.")` (this will help you find the file and line of code where the error occurred, when debugging - `die()` will not offer your the same information, and you will have to search everywhere for it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [MySQL IN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) clause

```
<?php

$id = '1';

include_once 'include_once/connect.php';

// first we create an array with all xy
$array = array();
for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {
    for ($y = 1; $y <= 5; $y++) {
        $xy = $x."x".$y;
        $array[] = $xy;
    }
}

$in = "'" . implode("', '", $array) . "'";
$pullMapInfo = "SELECT xy, value FROM mapinfo WHERE id='".$id."' AND xy IN ({$in})";
$pullMapInfo2 = mysql_query($pullMapInfo) or die('error here');

// we create an associative array xy => value
$result = array();
while (($pullMapInfo3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($pullMapInfo2)) !== false) {
    $result[ $pullMapInfo3['xy'] ] = $pullMapInfo3['value'];
}


// we make a loop to display expected output
foreach ($array as $xy)
{
    if (array_key_exists($xy, $result)) {
        echo '<div class="castle_array" style="background-image: url(tiles/'.$result[$xy].'.BMP)" id="'.$xy.'">'. $result[$xy] .'</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="castle_array" id="'.$xy.'"></div>';
    }
    echo '<div class="clear_both"></div>';
}

?>
```

Comment: `$in = "'" . implode("', '", $array) . "'";
$pullMapInfo = "SELECT xy, value FROM mapinfo WHERE id='".$id."' AND xy IN {$in}";
$pullMapInfo2 = mysql_query($pullMapInfo) or die('error here');` returns "error here"

Comment: Excuse me, IN ({$in}), forgot parenthesis.

Comment: Ninsuo whats the difference between with and without this IN statement?

Comment: With the IN statement you only get elements that are defined inside the $array variable. So if in your database you have 1x1, 1x2, ... 5x5, 5x6, 6x1, ..., then you are sure to get only from 1x1 to 5x5. If you know there is only data from 1x1 to 5x5 in your DB, then IN is useless.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you have in your table, but considering you are basically looping through virtually everything in it, I'd say do a single query for the given Id and then sort out what you need from the larger dataset.

Especially if you are always pulling back essentially the complete dataset for each id, there's no reason to even bother with the `IN` query, just pull it all back into a single PHP array, and then iterate through that as needed.